# Taylor Series for $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

A function $f$ is defined as
$$
f(x) = 
\left
\{\begin{aligned}
&{cosx-1\over x^{2}} & for\,x \neq 0\\
&{-1\over 2} & for\,x=0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Using the first three non zero terms of the Taylor series for $cos\,x$ about $x=0$, write the first three non zero terms of the Taylor series for $f$ about $x=0$.

I have two concerns:

1. Does one really need the help of the Taylor series for $cos\,x$ about $x=0$, to write the first three non zero terms of the Taylor series for $f$ about $x=0$.
2. If one tries to write the Taylor series for $f(x)$ about $x=0$ directly, will it just be $f(x)\approx {-1\over2}$ because apparently $f'(0), f''(0), f'''(0)$ etc. are all equal to $0$?

Answer (score 0):

For all $x$ you have
$$\cos x -1= -\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{4!}x^4 - \frac{1}{6!}x^6 + \dots$$
hence in a neighbourhood of $0$ (and $x \neq 0$)
$$f(x)=\frac{\cos x -1}{x^2} = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4!}x^2 - \frac{1}{6!}x^4 + \dots$$
and this is the Taylor series of $f$ at $x=0$

In particular, it is not true that $f'(0), f''(0), f'''(0), \dots$ are all zero. Only odd derivatives vanish (that's because $f$ is an even function).

Comment: Can you please write the expressions you've used for $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ which made you arrive at a conclusion that $f'(x)\,at\,x=0$ (and other odd derivatives) vanish while $f''(x)\,at\,x=0$ (and other even derivatives) do not?

Comment: I didn't write the expression of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$: I recall you that $f^{(k)}(0) = a_k$, where $f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{k!}x^k$ is the Taylor expansion of $f$. So, for example, $f'(0)=0, f''(0)=1, f'''(0)=0, f^{(4)}(0)=-1$, and so on.

Comment: I know the structure of a Taylor expansion. I want to know how did you conclude $f'(0) = 0$, $f''(0) = 1$, $f'''(0) = 0$, $f''''(0) = -1$ etc without looking at the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$? In other words how does it directly follow from the definition of $f(x)$ that $f'(0) = 0$, $f''(0) = 1$, $f'''(0) = 0$, $f''''(0) = -1$ etc?

Comment: Strictly speaking, I used the definition of Taylor series in my answer: I found a Taylor expansion which coincides with $f(x)$ for all $x$, simply knowing the Taylor expansion of the cosine.